# Access Denied to Classic SharePoint Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, access-denied, classic-experience

I am a SCA and I "cleaned up" some SharePoint site permissions last week by removing membership groups from the Site Permissions list. This inadvertently caused everyone except Site Collection Admins to lose access to Classic Views. The users can still access pages and the content in Modern Views perfectly fine but if they try to access it in Classic View they get an access denied message. I created a test user account and assigned it Full Control permissions to replicate the problem on my end. Most of the site is still configured to utilize Class Views. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: When you say they can still access pages, are they Modern pages or Classic pages?  If your users are getting access denied when accessing Classic pages, I would check to see if you removed access to the Master Page Gallery somehow. Specifically, I would check to see if you removed the "Style Resource Readers" permission group.  This is the group that allows users to view the Master Page Gallery.

Comment: Users can still access classic Wiki Pages. I don't use any Modern Pages on this site. Its only when they try to view a List/Library in Classic View that the Access Denied error appears. The Access Denied message even appears if they click "Return to classic SharePoint" from the Site Contents page. 

I did remove it, but re-added it after I noticed the Access Denied message. I double checked and verified all users have read access to everything in the Master Page Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Finally determined what was causing the error. The Pages library did not have any permissions. I don't typically use this library but apparently permissions to it are necessary to view anything in Classic View.